# Wifi Adapter in Blazor wasm : System.DllNotFoundException: api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I've been trying to retrieve list of availables networks by using WifiAdapter.
I have a working solution that I've been testing in a console application :

```
        List<WiFiAvailableNetwork> networks = new();
        IEnumerable<WiFiAdapter> adapters = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
        foreach (WiFiAdapter adapter in adapters)
        {
            foreach (WiFiAvailableNetwork network in adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
            {
                networks.Add(network);
            }
        }
        return networks;
```

But once this solution is set in my blazor wasm project, it's crashing with this exception : **System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Windows.Devices.WiFi.WiFiAdapter' threw an exception.
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1  ---> System.DllNotFoundException: api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll**

I have been looking for an answer but I did not find any relevant solutions.
Any ideas on how to solve it/ why it is happening?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all parts of the .net platform are supported on all environments.

Blazor WebAssembly will not run anything from Windows.* .

When you want access to some device you will have to research if and how JavaScript can use it.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that Wasm was not desktop ready yet, I'm assuming that this piece of code will be available while wasm is running on desktop (at leasts I hope so).

Comment: WebAssembly is not heading for the Desktop. Some Blazor branches are. See Blazor on Electron or Mobile Bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **experimental** API from browser, calling it via JSRuntime in Blazor WASM.

Look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API